# Conflicts between different types of packets in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, networking, omnet++

I have created a simulation in OMNeT++ 
where I have one client and one server (both of them are UDPBasicApp modules). The client sends packets
to the server. The server also sends packets to the client, which are two subclasses of cPacket.

Unfortunately, there are conflicts between those two types of packets 
when they are received by the client. Let's assume that the types of the two packets are called
FirstPacket and SecondPacket respectively (classes derived from cPacket). By running the simulation, as soon as the client receives the first
packet from the server the simulation crashes and I get someting like the following error message:

```
"check_and_cast(): cannot cast (FirstPacket*).ClientServer.client.udpApp[0] to type SecondPacket"
```

How I can solve this problem? How the server can successfully  receive both types of packets sent by the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using something like `SecondPacket* p = check_and_cast<SecondPacket*>(pkt);` to force each incoming packet to be treated as being of type `SecondPacket`. OMNeT++'s `check_and_cast` will abort your simulation if this is not the case. A simple solution is to use a `dynamic_cast` instead:

```
PacketTypeA* a = dynamic_cast<PacketTypeA*>(pkt);
PacketTypeB* b = dynamic_cast<PacketTypeB*>(pkt);
if (a) {
  printf("got packet type A: %d", a->some_field_of_a);
}
if (b) {
  printf("got packet type B: %d", b->some_field_of_b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried what you said me, and it worked.